# Critical - contributions pages w/o monetary transactions or price sets don't save contributions but show confirmation page

Tags: contribution-page

I have a contribution page that's used to solicit in-kind donations. On the Amounts tab, **Execute real-time monetary transactions** is disabled, no Price Set is selected, but the **Allow other amounts** box is checked.

On attempting to submit this form, I get this notice:

messageNotice: Undefined variable: contribution in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution_Utils::processConfirm() (line 378 of /srv/buildkit/build/d46/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution/Utils.php).

And no contribution is saved. This behavior is replicable on the 4.6 sandbox (http://d46.demo.civicrm.org).

Regarding the error message, $contribution is not set because $form->_contributeMode is null.

Comment: what page on demo?

Comment: d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=4

Comment: interesting. read lots of old threads on forum about this. sounds like it isn't widely used and perhaps some 'fix' has been done that has rendered this non-functioning. See what others say but it may need to be put through as a bug to JIRA. may be worth trying to replicate on dmaster.demo.... too

Comment: "read" == "caused me to read", it wasn't meant to sound as if it was an instruction to you to do that reading.